# How to correlate two JSON objects via a key-value pair?

Tags: splunk

Imagine there are thousands of JSON entries and I want to correlate object pairs via a key/value pair.

Entry #44

`{
     speed: 55,
     distance: 18,
     time: 1481216486,
     color: red,
 }`

Entry #323

`{
     speed: 75,
     distance: 38,
     time: 1481216486,
     color: blue,
 }`

Search: `sourcetype=test_drive (DO THE MAGIC) | eval first_distance=distance(#44) | eval second_distance=distance(#323) | table time first_distance(#323) second_distance(#44)`

So basically I'm trying to find an entry pair via a key/value and use another key/value pair(s) to create a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the transaction filter here, http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.1/SearchReference/Transaction.  This won't gracefully merge your json in _raw, but it will make the properties available to query/chart upon.

In this example, I assume you want to merge events by the time property, since that is the only matching field.

```
sourcetype=test_drive (DO THE MAGIC) | eval first_distance=distance(#44) | eval second_distance=distance(#323) | transaction time | table time first_distance(#323) second_distance(#44)
```